# VB6 - Declaring and calling C DLL with pointers

Tags: c, dll, vb6

I have an old C DLL I use to call from Ruby, but now I need to call it from VB6 and I can't figure out the correct way to do so.

Here is the header for the function I need:

`int Decrunch(const BYTE *src, BYTE *dest, DWORD src_length)`

*src is a sequence of bytes which will be decrypted by the function

*dest is a buffer which will recieve the decrypted data. I can call the function with dest=NULL and it will return the size of the decrypted data, so I can use it to create the buffer with the correct size.

I tried to declare it with both src and dest as Strings (like I do in Ruby) but it won't work. I've also tried to declare them as Byte and pass the first element of a byte array as I was pointed by some tutorials, but I think I didn't do it correctly.

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Air code

```
Private Declare DecrunchGetLength Alias "Decrunch" Lib "somedll.DLL" (ByRef src As Byte, ByVal nullptr As Long, ByVal SrcLength As Long) As Long 

Private Declare Decrunch Alias "Decrunch" Lib "somedll.DLL" (ByRef src As Byte, ByRef dest As Byte, ByVal SrcLength As Long) As Long 

Dim destLen As Long
 Dim src(0 To 9) As Byte 
Dim dest() As Byte 

' get bytes into src somehow 

' get dest length 
destLen = DecrunchGetLen( src(0), 0, 10) 

ReDim dest(0 To destLen - 1) 
destLen = Decrunch( src(0), dest(0), 10)
```

Useful links

- [Declare statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243324%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)
- *Advanced* [calling C DLLs from VB5/VB6](http://vb.mvps.org/tips/vb5dll.asp)

Comment: Thank you! But I still get a "Bad DLL calling convention" when calling DecrunchGetLen. Any other ideas? Thank you for the links too.

Comment: It's not a cdecl DLL is it? http://factoryswblog.org/2007/10/25/vb6-notes-determining-the-calling-convention-of-a-c-dll/

Comment: I don't know. I'll have to check if the developer remembers this. I have the function algorithm, maybe it will be less trouble if I just translate the code or if I build another DLL.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed the link now. I'll follow the instructions and hope they help =) Thank you

Comment: Dumpbin won't get any decorated names, only normal names. I'll ask the developer.

Comment: Hummm...looks like it is a cdecl DLL. I didn't know, but if I build the VB6 program, the exe is able to call the function. I'll check if the functions work correctly after built. If not, I'll try to build a stdcall dll to call the other dll.

Comment: Compiled app tries to "fix" stack after calling your API function. It does not always succeed, needless to say how dangerous this is to leave in production code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a CDECL calling thunk like this

```
Option Explicit

'--- for VirtualProtect'
Private Const PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE    As Long = &H40

Private Declare Function VirtualProtect Lib "kernel32" (lpAddress As Any, ByVal dwSize As Long, ByVal flNewProtect As Long, lpflOldProtect As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" Alias "LoadLibraryA" (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function GetProcAddress Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hModule As Long, ByVal lpProcName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function CallWindowProc Lib "user32" Alias "CallWindowProcA" (ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As Long, ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal Msg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Private Const STR_MYDLL         As String = "my.dll"

Private Type UcsParamThunk
    pfn                     As Long
    Call_(0 To 7)           As Long
End Type

Private m_hModule           As Long
Private m_uCallThunk        As UcsParamThunk

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim baSrc()         As Byte
    Dim baDst()         As Byte

    On Error GoTo EH
    ReDim baSrc(0 To 10000) As Byte
    ReDim baDst(0 To 20000) As Byte
    pvCallFunc "Decrunch", VarPtr(baSrc(0)), VarPtr(baDst(0)), UBound(baSrc) + 1
    Exit Sub
EH:
    MsgBox Error$, vbCritical
End Sub

Private Function pvCallFunc(sFunc As String, ParamArray A()) As Long
    Dim pfn             As Long
    Dim lIdx            As Long
    Dim aParams()       As Long

    If m_hModule = 0 Then
        m_hModule = LoadLibrary(STR_MYDLL)
        If m_hModule = 0 Then
            Err.Raise vbObjectError, , STR_MYDLL & " not found"
        End If
        pvInitCallCdeclThunk m_uCallThunk
    End If
    pfn = GetProcAddress(m_hModule, sFunc)
    If pfn = 0 Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError, , "Export not found: " & sFunc
    End If
    ReDim aParams(0 To UBound(A) + 1) As Long
    For lIdx = 0 To UBound(A)
        aParams(lIdx) = CLng(A(lIdx))
    Next
    pvCallFunc = CallWindowProc(m_uCallThunk.pfn, pfn, UBound(aParams), VarPtr(aParams(0)), 0)
End Function

Private Sub pvInitCallCdeclThunk(Thunk As UcsParamThunk)
'void _stdcall thunk(int pfn, int count, int args, int dummy)
'        push    ebp
'        mov     ebp, esp
'        mov     ecx, count
'        jecxz   _skip_params
'        mov     edx, args
'_params_loop:
'        push    dword ptr [edx + ecx * 4 - 4]
'        loop    _params_loop
'_skip_params:
'        call pfn
'        mov     esp,ebp
'        pop     ebp
'        ret     10h
'        nop
'        nop
    With Thunk
        .Call_(0) = &H8BEC8B55
        .Call_(1) = &H9E30C4D
        .Call_(2) = &HFF10558B
        .Call_(3) = &HE2FC8A74
        .Call_(4) = &H855FFFA
        .Call_(5) = &HC25DE58B
        .Call_(6) = &H90900010
        .pfn = VarPtr(.Call_(0))
        Call VirtualProtect(Thunk, Len(Thunk), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, 0)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As a good general rule of thumb if you encounter pointers from other languages (C++ for example), you should declare them as "Any" in VB6:

```
Private Declare Decrunch Alias "Decrunch" Lib "somedll.DLL" (cpbSrc As Any, pbDest As Any, dwDataLength As Long) As Long
Dim cpbSrc(0 to 10) as byte, pbDest() as byte, dwDataLength as long
Call Decrunch(cpbSrc(0), Byval 0, dwDataLength)    ' Pass NULL pointer to return the length
Redim pbDest(0 to dwDataLength - 1)    ' initialize the pbDest array
Debug.Print Decrunch(cpbSrc(0), pbDest(0), dwDataLength)
```