# Trying to call a C DLL from VB. Can't get one of the parameters working

Tags: dll, vb6

Trying to set up a USB power strip.

Here's the documentation:

```
Initializes the Power USB API.

Name: InitPowerUSB 

Parameters: model:returns the model number(1:basic, 2:digIO, 3:watchdog, 4:Smart), firmware: returns firmware version in ?.? format in a character string (major revision and minor revision) 

Return: >0 if successful. Returns number of PowerUSB devices connected

C++ Example:

if (!m_pwrUSBInit)
{
    int model; char firmware[8];
    if ((ret=InitPowerUSB(&model, firmware)) > 0)
    {
        m_pwrUSBInit = 1;
        m_numDevices = ret;
    }
}
```

I have been trying to get this working with my VB6 code for around an hour now with no luck. The program either crashes, displays an error like `Bad Calling Dll Convention`, `type mismatch`, et cetera.

Here's what I have:

`Public Declare Function InitPowerUSB Lib "PwrUSBDll.dll" (ByRef model As Integer, ByVal firmware As String) As Integer`

```
Dim model As Integer
model = 0

Dim firmware As String
firmware = ""

If (InitPowerUSB(model, firmware)) > 0) Then

EndIf
```

I have tried changing firmware to byte arrays, byref, string, integer, long, etc. It just doesn't seem to want to run.

Does anyone know of a solution to this problem? Thanks

Comment: Declare Model as Long and terminate your string with vbNullChar. If doesn't help, then Bob Riemersma comment about calling convention should be considered.

Comment: Actually any String in VB6 is always terminated by a NUL "out of band" after the contents. This isn't copied to a Byte array when you assign a String to one, but the String itself is protected by the hidden "guard" character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't answer the rest of your function signature woes since I don't have any documentation for your `PwrUSBDll.dll`.

However "Bad DLL calling convention" errors generally mean you have a `CDecl` entrypoint and VB6 can only call those with some help.

There are a couple of fixes.

The obvious one is to modifiy the source and recompile that DLL using `StdCall` instead.

Another is to create a type library for that DLL, which helps inform VB6 about the issue and resolves it.

Then you have the option of using VB6's undocumented CDecl decorator:

```
Public Declare Function InitPowerUSB CDecl Lib "PwrUSBDll.dll" ( _
    ByRef model As Integer, _
    ByVal firmware As String) As Integer
```

However the downside is that this will not work when run within the IDE, nor will it work when compiled to p-code.  The p-code interpreter doesn't process this keyword.

So you could just bypass it in IDE runs and supply dummy results for testing, *or* you can create a small wrapper DLL in VB6 that you separately compile to native code.

**Caveats:**

For this to solve your problem we'd have to assume you are passing correct data types in that argument list.  A C++ `int` is a VB6 `Long`.  You are probably better off passing a VB6 `Byte` array `ByRef` for that `char[8]` unless this is a Unicode DLL entrypoint.  The function return value is also most likely `Long`.

Comment: It was a feature from QuickBasic/PDS.  But be careful: it was never fully implemented (i.e. the p-code interpreters in VB6.exe and in the runtime do not recognize it).  As far as I know it only works when compiled to native code.

Comment: Nice semi-implemented feature! So `CDecl` modifier make my cdecl calling thunk [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106234/vb6-declaring-and-calling-c-dll-with-pointers) kind of obsolete.

Comment: Kind of.  But the lack of support during IDE debugging runs can be a deal breaker for programs of any real size and complexity.  But as I mentioned you could create a VB6 wrapper DLL this way or use a custom TLB.  The advantage is that your programs run on DEP machines without having to selectively disable it for them.