# What's is the VB6 equivalent of a C++ char array?

Tags: c++, dll, vb6, char

I'm trying to call a DLL written in C++ from a VB6 application.

Here's the C++ example code for calling the DLL.

```
char firmware[32];
int maxUnits = InitPowerDevice(firmware);
```

However, when I try to call it from VB6 I get the error `bad DLL calling convention`.

```
Public Declare Function InitPowerDevice Lib "PwrDeviceDll.dll" (ByRef firmware() As Byte) As Long

Dim firmware(32) As Byte
InitPowerDevice(firmware)
```

**Edit: The C++ Prototype:**

```
Name: InitPowerDevice
Parameters: firmware: returns firmware version in ?.? format in a character string (major revision and minor revision)
Return: >0 if successful. Returns number of Power devices connected

CLASS_DECLSPEC int InitPowerDevice(char firmware[]);
```

Comment: this is stretching my memory a bit, but is it not ByVal x as String?

Comment: @PeteH: I tried that and it didn't work either.

Comment: Can you find the definition of that `CLASS_DECLSPEC` macro?

Comment: @BenVoigt CLASS_DECLSPEC is usually a 2 way define(through `#if/#else)` - while compiling the dll, it resolves to `__declspec(dllexport)` and when the header is included in `C` or `C++` calling code, it resolves to `__declspec(dllimport)`

Comment: Also `char firmware[32]` is either `Dim firmware(31) As Byte` or `Dim firmware(63) As Byte` depending on whether the C function was compiled for ANSI or Unicode. But that shouldn't impact the calling convention.

Comment: @Bob77: No, `char` is never Unicode.  You must be thinking of `TCHAR`, which changes size depending on compile settings.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Oops, you are correct Sir!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Been a long time, but I think you also need to change your C function to be stdcall.

```
// In the C code when compiling to build the dll
CLASS_DECLSPEC int __stdcall InitPowerDevice(char firmware[]);

' VB Declaration
Public Declare Function InitPowerDevice Lib "PwrDeviceDll.dll" _
        (ByVal firmware As String) As Long

' VB Call
Dim fmware as String
Dim r  as Long
fmware = Space(32)
r = InitPowerDevice(fmware)
```

I don't think VB6 supports calling `cdecl` functions in any normal way - there may be hacks for doing it. May be you can write a wrapper `dll` which wraps the `cdecl` function with a `stdcall` function and just forwards the call.

These are some hacks - but I haven't tried it.

http://planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=49776&lngWId=1

http://planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=62014&lngWId=1

Comment: @JohnSmith Could you give the prototype of your C funtion?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the original source code so I don't think I can change the function to `__stdcall`. I tried putting `Cdecl` on the VB6 function instead but I was met with the same error `bad DLL calling convention`.

Comment: @JohnSmith - you cannout put `cdecl` in vb6. Has to be done while creating the dll. Try writing a wrapper dll.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870101/trying-to-call-a-c-dll-from-vb-cant-get-one-of-the-parameters-working where this was already covered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a pointer to the beginning of the array contents, not a pointer to the SAFEARRAY.

Perhaps what you need is either:

```
Public Declare Function InitPowerDevice Lib "PwrDeviceDll.dll" ( _
    ByRef firmware As Byte) As Long

Dim firmware(31) As Byte
InitPowerDevice firmware(0)
```

or

```
Public Declare Function InitPowerDevice CDecl Lib "PwrDeviceDll.dll" ( _
    ByRef firmware As Byte) As Long

Dim firmware(31) As Byte
InitPowerDevice firmware(0)
```

The CDecl keyword only works in a VB6 program compiled to native code.  It never works in the IDE or in p-code EXEs.

Answer (score 0):

Since your error is "bad calling convention", you should try changing the calling convention.  C code use `__cdecl` by default, and IIRC VB6 had a `Cdecl` keyword you could use with `Declare Function`.

Otherwise you can change the C code to use `__stdcall`, or create a type library (.tlb) with the type information and calling convention.  That might be better than `Declare Function` because you use the C datatypes when defining the type library, but VB6 recognizes them just fine.

As far as the argument type is concerned, `firmware() As Byte` with `ByVal` (not `ByRef`) should be fine.

Comment: Yeah, I tried using Cdecl in the function declaration but that didn't seem to help either. Tried it with every combination of `ByRef`, `ByVal`, `As String`, and `() As Byte` to no avail.

Comment: VB.NET allows changing the calling convention. VB6 doesn’t – it only allowes stdcall.

Comment: Leaving out `ByRef` merely implies `ByRef`.  it is usually better to use it explicitly but it makes no difference either way.